# How to show div when hovering over span inside p tag

Tags: html, css

I have a `<p>` tag with a `<span>` inside it, and a `<div>` next to the `<p>` tag, like so:

```html
<div class="foo">
    <p class="bar">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="baz">amet.</span>
    </p>
    <div class="qux">
        <p>
            I'm hidden until you hover over baz!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it to where `.qux` is hidden until you hover over `.baz`, and I have the following css that doesn't seem to work:

```css
.qux {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.foo .baz:hover + .qux {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, and `.qux` does not show up on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that adding the `:has` selector solves this problem, as follows:

```css
.bar:has(> .baz:hover) + .qux {
    opacity: 1;
}
```